# Radius and interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I can't figure out how to attack this problem. Do I use the ratio test?

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{{x^2}^n}{n(\ln(n)^2)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obeserve there's a way to make your series an  *actual power series*:

$$a_n:=\begin{cases}\cfrac1{k\log^2k},&\exists\,1<k\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n=2^k\\{}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and then we get that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{2^n}}{n\log^2n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nx^n$$

and we can get the radius of convergence with the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem (Formula):

$$\frac1R=\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n\log^2n}}=1\implies R=1$$

and the convergence interval is $\;[-1,1]\;$

Comment: I appreciate this answer but unfortunately my teacher expects us to use the ratio test to find interval of convergence.. I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @MeganByers Well, it is going to be a real headache since if you're going to have to see this series as a **power series**, as I am guessing is the intention, you're going to have to do the same trick as above **and then** do the ratio test, which I suppose is going to be lengthy and cumbersome because of the different cases you'll have to consider... Good luck with that, though. And next time do not ask "Do I have to  use the ratio test?", but tell "I **have to use** the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Use the root test. Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\right)^{1/2^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{\ln(n\ln^2(n))}{2^n}\right).$$

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question - but the limit (or bounds) of this is essentially going to be my interval of convergence, right?